# Eu devo fechar minha propria pergunta?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Fiz a seguinte pergunta ontem: [Como é criado e configurado o banco de dados de uma aplicação WEB?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116744/como-%C3%A9-criado-e-configurado-o-banco-de-dados-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web)

Eu recebi dois comentários do usuário @ClaydersonFerreira, ele explicou nos comentários o processo de criação do banco. Entretanto, acredito que eu não formulei muito bem a pergunta (talvez pela minha falta de conhecimento da área de desenvolvimento WEB) e ela já recebeu três votos para ser fechada, o que já indica que tem algo de errado.

Como não recebi o feedback dos colegas que votaram para fechar, eu não sei em qual aspecto devo melhorar a pergunta. Gostaria que a comunidade me ajuda-se a melhorar a pergunta com sugestões ou que me orientasse a tomar a decisão de eu mesmo votar para fechar minha pergunta, caso a mesma não de para ser recuperada.

Comment: Os 3 votos são como "baseada em opiniões". acho que nesse caso o feedback é implícito. Nenhum dos votos é meu, mas entendo que não tem um "jeito certo" de responder. Depende da intenção de cada autor de cada aplicação. Se o cenário for fechado em algumas condições específicas, talvez melhor, mas corre-se o risco de editar e continuar baseada em opiniões, ou talvez ampla demais, por depender de fatores mil. Se tem um interesse prático na resposta, para resolver um problema específico, sugiro editar pra tentar melhorar. Se for só uma discussão teórica, talvez o chat seja mais adequado que o site

Comment: Tenho um interesse por traz, e minha intenção é ajudar novos usuários que acabaram de entrar na programação para WEB. Vou ver se consigo pesquisar mais a respeito disso e tentar isolar o máximo possível para criar uma pergunta mais objetiva, e que não seja baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Enquanto isso vou deixar a comunidade decidir se a pergunta deve ser fechada ou não. Mais qualquer outra sugestão é bem vinda.

Comment: Tente por parâmetros para deixar ela mais específica, ou pedir por vantagens e desvantagens específicas de cada uma das coisas. Lembre-se que mesmo depois de fechada, dá pra editar e pode ser reaberta.

Comment: @Bacco Vc conseguiu entender a pergunta com facilidade ou teve alguma dificuldade em entender a necessidade expressada na pergunta?

Comment: Eu entendi a pergunta, mas também entendo que não tem resposta objetiva da forma em que se encontra. Note que os votos pra fechar não são por não estar clara, e sim por ser baseada em opiniões. Se não desse pra entender, provavelmente os votos seriam "não está clara".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu concordo com os comentários do Bacco: a pergunta está clara, mas não tem uma resposta objetiva.

Eu poderia citar meia dúzia de técnicas de como criar um banco de dados de uma aplicação web e mais meia dúzia de maneiras de manter ele atualizado a cada versão do sistema (aliás, já tenho algumas respostas que descrevem isso parcialmente.

Algumas dessas técnicas são usadas por empresas acidentalmente (falta de conhecimento, falta de pesquisa, por políticas do fornecedor ou do cliente, porque a certificação de qualidade/segurança diz que precisa ser de tal forma, porque o DBA não deixa ninguém colocar a mão no banco, etc.

Enfim, depende da aptidão, gosto, plataforma, bibliotecas disponíveis, frameworks adotados, das restrições do projeto e outros.

Mesmo no exemplo de Desktop que você citou, o que você escreveu não é verdade. Você está supondo que a aplicação desktop roda no cliente localmente e é distribuída através de algum instalador. Entretanto, todas as aplicações desktop que eu conheço são disponibilizadas via JNDI e acessam o banco de dados via rede ou internet, já que todos os usuários precisam acessar os mesmos dados.

Além disso, *configurar* é um termo muito amplo. Você está incluindo a instalação do SGBD, definição de usuários, papéis e níveis de acesso? Cada implementação de banco é diferente.

Uma sugestão seria adicionar um contexto mais específico. Se a ideia é ajudar quem está começando com Java, pergunte sobre uma configuração simples para quem não usa frameworks e está desenvolvimento na máquina local. Se a ideia é ajudar quem está começando uma *startup* ou tentando colocar um produto pela primeira vez no ar a resposta seria completamente diferente.

Além do mais, **defina uma tecnologia**. MySQL? PostgreSQL? Se você não quer entrar em detalhes, limite sua pergunta à configuração da aplicação e não da configuração do banco de dados.

Outra estratégia é quebrar a pergunta em várias. Exemplo:

- Como fazer uma configuração básica do Hibernate com o MySQL?
- Como inicializar um banco de dados usando apenas JDBC?
- Como fazer inicializar um banco de dados se ele estiver vazio?

Concluindo, eu acho legal você ter feito esta pergunta e acho legal sua iniciativa de ajudar os novatos. Eu considero muito importante que o SO tenha esse tipo de pergunta comum que vai ser usada milhares e milhares de vezes. Entretanto, para ser útil de verdade, ela precisa ser mais específica e objetiva.

Comment: Obrigado por sua contribuição, vcs me conversaram que é melhor fechar a pergunta e procurar outras formas de abordar este assunto de uma maneira mais objetiva e evitando que seja baseada em opiniões. Vou pesquisar formas e estudar mais para fazer perguntas deste tipo, gosto muito de contribuir para que o SOpt tenha seu conteúdo com qualidade.